# IBM Watson Assistant: Trying to evaluate and compare multiple context variables

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've just started trying out Watson Assistant and have no clue what I'm doing. 
I'm trying to built a chatbot that asks a series of questions and then outputs an evaluation based on the user's inputs.

E.g. Inputs:

> Q1 "How many apples do you have?"
>
> Q2 "How many apples does your neighbour have?"
>
> Q3 "Did you eat any apples?"

With my desired output as:

```
IF ((Q1 > Q2) AND Q3 = "No") 
  THEN output "You have more apples"
ELSEIF ((Q1 > Q2) AND Q3 = "Yes")
  THEN output "You might not have more apples"
ENDIF
```

I've currently used slots to collect all the inputs in one node but I don't know how to evaluate them to give the correct outputs.

Answer (score 0):

In Watson Assistant inside the skill / dialog editor, you can edit the responses. For a response it is possible to contain expressions. The documentation for Watson Assistant has a section on [Expression anguage methods](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods) and on [Expressions for accessing objects](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language). I have several examples in this GitHub repo [Watson Conversation Variables](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables) which demonstrate how to evaluate the context variables and produce and output like you want.

Look here on [how to use the ternary operator](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#conditions-and-predicates-in-the-response).